# Azure Devops - API to promote package to pre-release/release views

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

We are using azure devops CI/CD in our current deployment.  As part of the automation, i am looking for API/python sdk for promoting the any azure artifact to prerelease/release.  It seems the documentation is not clear.

Please advise.

Solution

```
curl -u username:password_pat -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X PATCH --data '{ "views": { "from":"", "op":"add", "path":"/views/-", "value":"Release"}}' https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedid}/upack/packages/{package_name}/versions/{package_version}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk: Let me try that. Will it work for universal package ?

Comment: I’m didn’t try with universal :/